# Python Nslookup domain list issue

Tags: python-3.x

New to python and I am using Python 3.7

I have a list of domains. I wanna read these domains from a text file and then check nslookup. But this code is not working. What's wrong with this code?
Please let me know the solution.

```
import dns.resolver,os
new_txt = open("Domain_check.txt","w")
with open(os.getcwd()+"\\\Domains.txt", "r") as f:
 for date in f:
  dateb = str(date)
  dateb = dateb.replace("\n"," ")
  answers = dns.resolver.resolve(dateb, 'A')
  for rdate in answers:
   b = str(dateb) + str(rdate)
   new_txt.write(b)
```

My Domain list is :
google.com、yam.com

Try to result as below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message `The DNS query name does not exist: yahoo.com\032.` gives a hint: there's an additional character at the end of the address. This is because when you read the Domains.txt file, you replace the linebreaks with a space - incidentally, that's code 32 in ASCII. Do this instead:

```py
import dns.resolver

with open("Domains.txt", "r") as in_file, \
     open("Domain_check.txt", "w") as out_file:

    for line in in_file:
        qname = line.strip()
        answers = dns.resolver.resolve(qname, 'A')
        for rdata in answers:
            output = qname + ' ' + str(rdata)
            out_file.write(output)
```

I fixed a few other issues with the code. Please feel free to ask if anything is unclear.

Comment: Hi @Jan Wilamowski, Thank you for your help and I have changed some code.  

`output = str(line) + ' ' +str(rdata)
            out_file.write(output +"\n")`

Text result as below:
`google.com
 172.217.160.110
yam.com 13.76.85.56`

Thank you

Comment: @Hsin I mistyped a variable name (domain instead of qname), sorry about that. It's fixed now. Glad to hear you still found the solution useful!